# Ошибка InvalidArgument=Значение '1' недопустимо для 'index'

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть кнопка "Данные процесса" которая выводит ID процесса, время запуска и юзер тайм.В лист боксе все работало нормально, я сменил лист бокс на list view и эта кнопка полетела.
Вот ошибка

> ! System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException не обработано
>     HResult=-2146233086
>     Message=InvalidArgument=Значение '1' недопустимо для 'index'.
>   Имя параметра: index
>     Source=System.Windows.Forms
>     ParamName=index

Код

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Process[] task = Process.GetProcesses();
  foreach (Process proc in task) 
  { // В этой строке ошибка -     
    if (LstProc.SelectedIndices[1].ToString() == proc.ProcessName)
    {
      string temp = string.Empty;
      temp += "ID Процесса:" + proc.Id.ToString();
      temp += "\nПользовательское время :" + proc.UserProcessorTime.ToString();
      temp += "\nЗапущенно в:" + proc.StartTime.ToString();  
      MessageBox.Show(temp, "Данные о процессе");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Количество  `LstProc.SelectedIndices` меньше двух.

Comment: Это что? Если у Вас есть/появилась новая информация, добавьте ее в вопрос.

Comment: Прежде чем делать это: `LstProc.SelectedIndices[1].ToString() ` надо проверить размерность массива, можно ли запрашивать по этому индексу что-либо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный код выводит сообщение о процессе и без проверки, правда только о 1 процессе

```
        Process[] task = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process proc in task)
        { 
                {
                    string temp = string.Empty;
                    temp += "ID Процесса:" + proc.Id.ToString();
                    temp += "\nПользовательское время :" + proc.UserProcessorTime.ToString();
                    temp += "\nЗапущенно в:" + proc.StartTime.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(temp, "Данные о процессе");
                    break;
                }
        }
```

Я вижу такой вариант.  Выбираем процесс в списке, нажимаем на кнопку. получаем сообщение о процессе

```
        Process[] task = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process proc in task)
        {
            if(LstProc.Items[LstProc.SelectedIndices[0]].Text == proc.ProcessName)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("-------------------"+LstProc.SelectedIndices.Count);
                    string temp = string.Empty;
                    temp += "ID Процесса:" + proc.Id.ToString();
                    temp += "\nПользовательское время :" + proc.UserProcessorTime.ToString();
                    temp += "\nЗапущенно в:" + proc.StartTime.ToString();
                    temp += "Имя: " + proc.ProcessName;
                    MessageBox.Show(temp, "Данные о процессе");
                    break;
                }
        }
```